# fb request dialog filter not working

Tags: request, facebook-javascript-sdk

We are using  Request dialog

```
method  : 'apprequests',
new_style_message: true,
message : 'msg',
display: 'popup',
title : 'sometitle',
filters: ['app_non_users'],
to : [array of id]
```

As our users will be inviting their friends to app, our intention is to get  `App_non_users` filter to work with combination of  `to` array.

So if we pass `to` the array [id1,id2,id3], and if `id1` is already user of the app, App request should only delivered to rest of the two id!

But looks like it is not working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of the `filter` parameter is not 100% correct.  The `filter` parameter tells the Facebook multiselector dialog what to display.  It has nothing to do with who the request gets sent to if you *also* include the `to` parameter.

From the Facebook request dialog documentation - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

> This controls what set of friends the user sees if a Multi Friend Selector is shown.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it manually ... get user friend list , exclude friends already register in your db as app user and then fill the dialog with the to array

Answer (score 0):

See the Facebook bug for this:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/151958874949988/

It's been broken for a year, so you're going to have to work around it.